# Resources for learning Mandarin Chinese

Tags: mandarin, resources

This is a [community-maintained list of resources](https://chinese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/162) for learning Mandarin Chinese.

#### Alphabetical Index

- [Add-ons (browser)](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/1325)
- [AI chat bots](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/54389/8099)
- [Apps](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/2523)
- [Books](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/1125)
- [Dictionaries](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/1195)
- [Language Exchanges](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/2663)
- [Lists of Resources](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/41018)
- [News](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/1213)
- [Online Courses and Tutors](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/1122)
- [Online Tests](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/45747)
- [Podcasts](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/1123)
- [Social Media](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/17648/8099)
- [Software](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/2437)
- [Textbooks](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/1121)
- [Websites](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/1233)

Just write in the appropriate answer/section. If you have concerns, questions, [post a meta question](https://chinese.meta.stackexchange.com/), so we don't clutter the comments, but you can link your meta question from the comments.

#### Organization

- Answers have a type of resource **each**.
- Please **do not** include links to unlawful content (note: we are not international copyright lawyers).  If a resource is listed, it does not imply we endorse it.
- [Both free and commercial resources are allowed](https://chinese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/159), but make sure to include a note if they are. Remember the [rules about self-promotion](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion). Include also if registration is required.
- Include links to the sites only, *don't post images*, they would take too much space.
- Add the resources **in alphabetical order** so they're easier to find.
- Please only include resources that have some kind of notoriety (we don't want to be flooded by useless resources).

*Note: new rules could be added in the future.*

Comment: Few people ever realize, that it's not about the resources. It's how you use them. Most of those shiny ipad and smartphone apps are useless toys. Apps don't learn Chinese, it's you who need to make the efforts, which no app can replace. Computer aid hardly makes language learning any better. The only thing in this context a computer can help you is getting access to target language media. The rest is mostly just (commercial) products you don't need. You most likely download and install way more stuff than you can use and profit from.

Comment: @KovácsImre I disagree. Apps provide extremely valuable help for reading that open up many new possibilities. See for instance http://www.hackingchinese.com/the-new-paperless-revolution-in-chinese-reading/

Answer (score 31):

### Websites

**Blogs**

- [Hacking Chinese](https://www.hackingchinese.com/)
- [Sinosplice](https://www.sinosplice.com/)

**Databases**

See also [Dictionaries](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/1195).

- [9610 Shufazidian](http://9610.com/zidian/index.htm) is a database of calligraphic variants.
- [Chinese Linguipedia](http://chinese-linguipedia.org/) is a database of glyph origins.
- [ChinesePoetry](http://chinese-poems.com)
- [Chinese text project](https://ctext.org/) is a database of pre-modern Chinese texts.
- [Dictionary of Chinese Character Variants](http://dict.variants.moe.edu.tw/variants/rbt/home.do)
- [Learn Chinese Club](https://learnchinese.club/) catalogues YouTube videos for learning Chinese.
- [A List of Chinese names](http://technology.chtsai.org/namelist/) by Chih-Hao Tsai.
- [List of Chinese classifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Chinese_classifiers) at Wikipedia.
- [Little Prince Collection](https://petit-prince-collection.com/lang/show_langue.php?lang=en&id=58): 971 "The Little Prince" books in Mandarin.
- [Multi-function Chinese Character Database](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/) provides ancient character forms and glyph origins.
- [Shtooka](http://shtooka.net/overview.php?lang=cmn) provides Chinese word audio pronunciations.
- [Täglich Chinesisch](http://taeglich.chinesisch-trainer.de/index.php?alle=1) (German) characters and components database.
- [Wengu](http://wengu.tartarie.com/wg/wengu.php?l=intro) provides classical Chinese works.
- [Xiao xue tang](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/) provides ancient character variants, oracle bones, seal scripts, etc.

**Example sentences**

- [Bing Dictionary](https://www.bing.com/dict/)
- [ChinesePod](https://chinesepod.com/dictionary/english-chinese)
- [iChacha](http://www.ichacha.net/mzj/)
- [Glosbe](https://glosbe.com/zh/en)
- [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/)
- [Leiden Weibo Corpus](http://lwc.daanvanesch.nl/)
- [LINE Dict](https://dict.naver.com/linedict/zhendict/#/cnen/home)
- [Purple Culture](https://www.purpleculture.net/sample-sentences/)
- [Tatoeba](https://tatoeba.org/eng/) (also [downloadable](https://tatoeba.org/eng/downloads))
- [We Hanyu](http://www.wehanyu.com/) extracts example sentences (segmented with pinyin) from videos.
- [YouDao](http://youdao.com/)
- [YouGlish](https://youglish.com/chinese) finds examples on YouTube.
- [Zaoju Wang 造句网](https://zaojv.com/)
- [Zhonga](https://www.zhonga.ru/) (in Russian).
- [Chinese Zero to Hero](https://www.zerotohero.ca/en/cmn/youtube/search) finds examples on YouTube.

**Flashcards and Writing**

- [Skritter](http://skritter.com) for writing practice.  Subscriptions are [$US 14.99 per month](https://legacy.skritter.com/pricing).
- [TOFU Learn](https://www.tofulearn.com/) for writing practice.

**Forum**

- [Chinese Forums](https://www.chinese-forums.com/)
- [Chinese Stack Exchange](http://chinese.stackexchange.com/)
- [Pleco Software Forum](https://www.plecoforums.com/)
- Reddit's [r/ChineseLanguage](http://reddit.com/r/ChineseLanguage/)
- [WordReference.com](http://forum.wordreference.com/forumdisplay.php?f=72)

**General learning**

- [cchatty](http://www.cchatty.com/)
- [ChineseKuang](http://www.chinesekuang.com/)
- [Dong Chinese](https://www.dong-chinese.com/) - paid version starts at [$US 9.99 per month](https://www.dong-chinese.com/pricing)
- [FluentU](http://fluentu.com) starts at [$US 20 per month](https://www.fluentu.com/pricing/).
- [Glossika](https://ai.glossika.com) focuses on learning, and starts at [$US 24.99 per month](https://ai.glossika.com/pricing).
- [Hack Chinese](https://www.hackchinese.com/) starts at [$US 8 per month](https://www.hackchinese.com/pricing).
- [Language Reactor](https://www.languagereactor.com/) assists watching YouTube videos.
- [Laowai's Unofficial Chengyu Guide](https://laowaichengyuguide.com/).
- [lingologue](https://lingologue.vercel.app/) gives oral translation exercises.
- [Ninchanese](https://ninchanese.com/) starts at [$US 10 per month](https://ninchanese.com/pricing/).
- [Pimsleur](https://www.pimsleur.com/) for languages in general, includes Mandarin [starting at $US 19.95 per month](https://www.pimsleur.com/learn-chinese-mandarin/subscription-premium).
- [Ponddy Reader](https://reader.ponddy.com) for teaching and learning, starts at [$US 9.99 per month](https://reader.ponddy.com/pricing/).
- [Speechling](https://speechling.com/) for speaking practice.
- [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/) starts at $US 12.95 per month.  See also: [PinYin Chart](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-pinyin-chart.php) with audio.
- [Yoyo Chinese](https://www.yoyochinese.com) bundles [start at $US 88](https://www.yoyochinese.com/store).
- [ZBSchools](https://zbschools.sg/) has Mandarin videos and reading materials for a Singaporean children.

**Grammar**

- [Chinese Boost](https://www.chineseboost.com/)
- [Chinese Grammar Wiki](http://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/)
- [LanguageTool](https://languagetool.org/) grammar checker.
- [Sapling](https://sapling.ai/lang/chinese) grammar checker.
- [Sentence Checker](https://sentencechecker.com/)
- [TextGears](https://textgears.com/chinese-grammar-online) grammar checker.
- [Yufalaoshi](https://yufalaoshi.com) grammar checker.

**Multimedia lessons**

- [Global Language Online Support System (GLOSS)](http://gloss.dliflc.edu/) provides free audio lessons with transcripts.
- [Learn Chinese Through Stories 听故事学中文](https://learningchinesethroughstories.com/)
- [中国大学MOOC](https://www.icourse163.org/): online Coursera-like courses in Chinese.

**Reading**

- [Archive of our Own](https://archiveofourown.org/) has fan fiction [in Chinese](https://archiveofourown.org/works/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&work_search%5Blanguage_id%5D=zh).
- [Easy Chinese](https://easychinese.io/) offers simplified news (Vietnamese website).
- [Chinese News Club](https://chinesenewsclub.substack.com/)
- [Chinese Reader's Guild](https://www.chinesereadersguild.com/)
- [Chinese Reading Practice](http://chinesereadingpractice.com/)
- [Chinese Sentence Scrambler](https://chinesescramble.netlify.app/)
- [Clozemaster](http://clozemaster.com/) "fill in the blanks" game (includes Chinese).
- [电子课本网](http://www.dzkbw.com) provides textbooks (e.g. 语文) used in Chinese schools.
- [HSK Reading](https://hskreading.com/)
- [故事101](https://www.story101.site/) has chengyu backstories, and other short stories.
- [LanguageCrush](https://languagecrush.com/) tracks words while reading, with various subscriptions e.g. [$US 5 per month](https://languagecrush.com/pricing).
- [LingQ](https://www.lingq.com/en/) tracks words while reading, with various subscriptions e.g. [$US 107.88 for 12 months](https://www.lingq.com/en/accounts/subscription/).
- [My Chinese Reading](https://mychinesereading.com/)
- [MyLingua](https://www.mylingua.world/) tracks words while reading news articles at various levels.
- [Nanshasi123](http://www.nanshansi123.com/) provides 语文 textbooks used in Chinese schools.
- [Project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/browse/languages/zh) provides Chinese novels.
- [七故事儿童网](http://www.qigushi.com/) has children's stories.
- [Ricciwawa](https://www.ricciwawa.com) has short stories with audio.
- [RuiWen](http://www.ruiwen.com/) has articles e.g. [作文](http://www.ruiwen.com/zuowen/) written by Chinese children.
- [Sinomemes](https://sinomemes.com/) explains Chinese memes.
- [WordPack](https://word-pack.com/) has HSK5-level sentences.
- [XKCD comics](https://xkcd.in/) in Chinese.

**Text-to-speech**

- [MicMonster](https://micmonster.com/text-to-speech/chinese-mandarin-simplified/)
- [Narakeet](https://www.narakeet.com/languages/chinese-text-to-speech/)
- [Natural Readers](https://www.naturalreaders.com/)
- [Speechify](https://speechify.com/text-to-speech-online/chinese/)
- [Talkify](https://talkify.net/)
- [TTSFree](https://ttsfree.com/text-to-speech/chinese-mandarin-simplified)
- [Veed.io](https://www.veed.io/tools/text-to-speech-video/chinese-text-to-speech)

(There's also multiple text-to-speech websites like [TextToVoice](https://www.texttovoice.online/?lang=cmn-CN) and [TTSmp3](https://ttsmp3.com/text-to-speech/Chinese%20Mandarin/) which seem to all use the same API.)

**Translation and OCR**

- [Baidu Translate 百度翻译](https://fanyi.baidu.com/)
- [Bing Microsoft Translator](https://www.bing.com/translator)
- [DeepL Translate](https://www.deepl.com/en/translator)
- [Google Translate](https://translate.google.cn/)
- [OCR.Space](https://ocr.space/)
- [Translate an image](https://translateimages.site/)
- [Yandex Translates](https://translate.yandex.com/) includes file and image uploads.

**Web tools**

- [Captionz](https://pnlpal.dev/captionz) generates subtitles for YouTube videos.
- [Chinese Text Analyzer](https://dimusic.github.io/chinese-text-analyzer/) analyzes text for HSK words.
- [Chinese Text Project](https://ctext.org/dictionary.pl?if=en) allows search by radical.
- [Chinese Tools](https://www.chinese-tools.com/) has a range of tools, e.g. [search by radical](https://www.chinese-tools.com/tools/sinograms.html?r=).
- [HSK Check](https://wumaocorp.com/hskcheck/tools/text-analyzer) estimates the HSK level on an input text.
- [HSK东西](http://hskhsk.pythonanywhere.com/hanzi) enumerates HSK characters and words in text; see also the [HSK data](https://github.com/glxxyz/hskhsk.com/tree/main/data/lists).
- [JCJC错别字在线检测](http://www.cuobiezi.net/) checks for typos in Chinese text.
- [Language Learning with Netflix](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/language-learning-with-ne/hoombieeljmmljlkjmnheibnpciblicm) is a Chrome extension that helps you watch (e.g.) Chinese language content on Netflix with/out subtitles, auto-pause, adjustable speed and built in lookup functions.
- [pin1yin1.com](http://pin1yin1.com/) adds pinyin or Zhuyin to text.
- [QHanzi](https://www.qhanzi.com/) allows character input via hand drawing.
- [NJStar](https://www.njstar.com/cms/cjk-code-to-unicode-conversion) converts Chinese GBK, Big5, etc. to Unicode.
- [Worchid](http://www.worchid.com/) allows typing Chinese by inputting English, pinyin, or bopomofo.
- [Word Similarity](https://wordsimilarity.com) lists similar words to an input word.

Comment: [Git游戏](http://gityx.com/) has Chinese versions of games posted to Github.

Comment: [Influent DLC - 普通话](https://store.steampowered.com/app/286961/Influent_DLC___Learn_Mandarin_Chinese/) is a Chinese-learning game.

Comment: [Chinese Character Alchemy](https://spotky1004.com/Chinese-Character-Alchemy/) (also [here](https://galaxy.click/play/68)) is a game where you combine components into (traditional) characters.

Answer (score 29):

### Browser Add-ons

**General**

- [Bilibili selectable danmu comments](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/448301-bilibili-selectable-danmu-comments) is a script which converts Bilibili on-screen comments to plaintext
- Chinese Tutor (Chrome: [Flashcards](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chinesetutor-flashcards/egbbefchlgcnhjoncjebmkffamidfhae), [Speaking](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chinesetutor-speaking/lpflafdbjlkiabamakjkmjclmfkchfjh), [Dictionary](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chinesetutor-dictionary/glfkbeoehpfomhdacjdnjaompnmadnhj), [Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chinese-tutor-dictionary/gfieiijcebhmabioenbhbeegmakmabil)) is a flashcard extension
- [Chinese Words Separator](https://www.reddit.com/r/ChineseLanguage/comments/npuqf6/chinese_words_separator/) ([Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chinese-words-separator/gacfacdpfimbkgcnlegknnmcccjgcbnp); [Safari](https://apps.apple.com/app/chinese-words-separator/id1598790017) $US 9.99; [Edge](https://microsoftedge.microsoft.com/addons/detail/chinese-words-separator/peglphdebebicogkcpinemlaanfabeip))
- [Flixlingo](https://www.flixlingo.com/) ([Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/flixlingo/nljiiplakcgjilhoopommpbpmjafkmlg))
- [Language Learning with Netflix](https://languagelearningwithnetflix.com/) ([Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hoombieeljmmljlkjmnheibnpciblicm))
- Language Learning with YouTube ([Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/language-learning-with-yo/jkhhdcaafjabenpmpcpgdjiffdpmmcjb))
- New Tong Wen Tang ([Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/new-tong-wen-tang/ldmgbgaoglmaiblpnphffibpbfchjaeg?hl=en); [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/new_tongwentang/)) converts between simplified and traditional Chinese
- Hanzisize ([Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hanzisize/jcljolcajgicemckjlgndbmoaeoobodk)) enlarges Chinese text
- Immersive Translate ([Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/immersive-translate/bpoadfkcbjbfhfodiogcnhhhpibjhbnh); [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/immersive-translate/)) inserts translations into webpages.
- TransOver ([Chrome](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/transover/aggiiclaiamajehmlfpkjmlbadmkledi); [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/transover-ff/)) translates text selection.
- [Toucan](https://jointoucan.com/) ([Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/toucan-language-learning/lokjgaehpcnlmkebpmjiofccpklbmoci); [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/toucan-language-learning/)) replaces words with those in your target language.
- [Vocabtracker](https://www.vocabtracker.com/) ([Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vocab-tracker/dmnblpfefmpaflamlfgmimhkmdmhlcda))

There are also many browser highlighters available (too many to list; [Google it](https://www.google.com/search?q=browser%20highlighter%20extension)), which enable you to highlight and save text for later review.

**Popup dictionaries**

- [Chinese Words Separator](https://www.reddit.com/r/ChineseLanguage/comments/npuqf6/chinese_words_separator/) ([Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chinese-words-separator/gacfacdpfimbkgcnlegknnmcccjgcbnp); [Safari](https://apps.apple.com/app/chinese-words-separator/id1598790017); [Edge](https://microsoftedge.microsoft.com/addons/detail/chinese-words-separator/peglphdebebicogkcpinemlaanfabeip))
- [Dictionaries: one to rule them all](https://github.com/pnlpal/dictionaries) includes Chinese ([Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dictionaries-one-to-rule/diojcfpekhhnndfmggknljpnfpcccbhc); [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dictionaries/); [Edge](https://microsoftedge.microsoft.com/addons/detail/dictionaries-one-to-rule/jdgglojanbnghagoeffacmjodigadoof))
- Perapera Chinese ([Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/perapera-chinese/))
- [Frill](https://frill.miknight.com/) (Safari)
- [GlotDojo](https://glotdojo.com/) ([Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/glotdojo-learn-languages/dbnjpielondlkmdjbembloegkaabfakc)) with [Chinese premium](https://glotdojo.com/premium/chinese)
- Inkah ([Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/inkah-chinese-korean-pop/pcgmedbmchghfgikplcimdmfldfnecec); [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/inkah/))
- LiuChan Chinese Popup Dictionary ([Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/liuchan-chinese-popup-dic/hjpjmkjmkgedphipmbnmejlnfndjcgdf); [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/liuchan/))
- [Popover Chinese](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/popover-chinese/id1548419843) (Safari)
- [Zhongwen: The Popular Chinese Learning Tool](https://github.com/cschiller/zhongwen) ([Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/zhongwen-chinese-english/kkmlkkjojmombglmlpbpapmhcaljjkde); [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/zhongwen/))
- Zhongzhong: An improved Chinese Dictionary ([Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/zhongzhong-an-improved-ch/dggcgdjndddfmcfoipccicfoajmciacf))

Answer (score 21):

### Software for learning

- [Anki](https://apps.ankiweb.net/) is an SRS program with [Chinese decks](https://ankiweb.net/shared/decks/chinese) (e.g. the [Spoonfed](https://ankiweb.net/shared/info/53920083) and [Tingli](https://ankiweb.net/shared/decks/Tingli) decks).
- [Mnemosyne](http://www.mnemosyne-proj.org/) is a free downloadable SRS program, with some decks for [Chinese](https://mnemosyne-proj.org/category/chinese).

### Tools

- [Chinese Comprehension](https://github.com/Destaq/chinese-comprehension) analyzes text for HSK words.
- [Chinese Sentence Miner](https://github.com/Destaq/chinese-sentence-miner) extracts example sentences from a database of 18000+ sentences.
- [DeepSpeech](https://github.com/mozilla/DeepSpeech/wiki#frequently-asked-questions) speech-to-text converts sound files to plaintext; it has an "experimental" [Mandarin Chinese](https://github.com/mozilla/DeepSpeech/releases) model.
- Ibus ([Github](https://github.com/ibus/ibus); [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/ibus/)) is a [Chinese input framework for Unix/Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_Input_Bus) (e.g. [Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ibus)).
- [Hanzi Writer](https://hanziwriter.org/) is a javascript library for character animations.
- `iconv` is a Unix command for converting between character encoding, e.g., `iconv -c -t=UTF-8` can be used to convert to UTF-8.
- [Jieba](https://github.com/fxsjy/jieba) is a free tool for Chinese text segmentation, written in Python.
- [MacOSX Language Tools](https://github.com/mingsai/MacOSX-Language-Tools) includes Chinese-English dictionaries, character-to-pinyin conversion, etc.
- Microsoft Edge's Read Aloud function is [noted for its high quality text-to-speech](https://www.reddit.com/r/ChineseLanguage/comments/grv8ey/psa_%E6%88%91%E5%8B%92%E4%B8%AA%E5%8E%BBmicrosoft_edge_read_aloud_function_is_the/) (see also [Guide on how to use Microsoft Azure's Text-to-Speech engine](https://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/107h4ax/guide_on_how_to_use_microsoft_azures_texttospeech/)).
- [OpenCC](https://github.com/BYVoid/OpenCC) converts between simplified and traditional characters; its [dictionaries](https://github.com/BYVoid/OpenCC/tree/master/data/dictionary) are available ([characters](https://github.com/BYVoid/OpenCC/blob/master/data/dictionary/STCharacters.txt); [phrases](https://github.com/BYVoid/OpenCC/blob/master/data/dictionary/STPhrases.txt)).

Answer (score 20):

### Language Exchanges

Websites to find language exchange partners, tutors, teachers; people will meet in person or talk online and help each other learn each others' respective languages.

- [Amazing Talker](https://en.amazingtalker.com/tutors/chinese)
- [Busuu](http://www.busuu.com/)
- [Classgap](https://www.classgap.com/en/chinese-online-tutors)
- [Conversation Exchange](http://www.conversationexchange.com/)
- [Free4Talk](https://www.free4talk.com/)
- [HelloTalk](https://www.hellotalk.com/)
- [Hinative](https://hinative.com/)
- [italki](http://www.italki.com/)
- [LangCorrect](https://langcorrect.com/) for writing corrections.
- [The Mixxer](http://www.language-exchanges.org/)
- [My Language Exchange](http://www.mylanguageexchange.com/)
- [Polyglot Club](http://polyglotclub.com/)
- [Preply](https://preply.com/)
- Reddit's [r/language_exchange](http://reddit.com/r/language_exchange) and [r/WriteStreakCN/](https://www.reddit.com/r/WriteStreakCN/)
- [Speaky](https://www.speaky.com/)
- [Verbling](https://www.verbling.com/)

Answer (score 19):

### Apps

**Dictionaries**

- Hanping Chinese Dictionary Pro 汉英词典 ([Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.embermitre.hanping.app.pro); $US 2.99) includes handwriting recognition, native speaker audio, stroke animations, example sentences, idioms, HSK words, etc. More functionality via in-app purchases, e.g. [Hanping Camera](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.embermitre.hanping.app.reader.pro) ($US 9.99) and [Hanping Chinese Popup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.embermitre.hanping.app.popup) ($US 9.99).
- [Pleco](http://www.pleco.com/) ([iOS](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/pleco-chinese-dictionary/id341922306); [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pleco.chinesesystem)) free dictionary with example sentences; many additional features e.g. OCR via in-app purchases.
- Ponddy Chinese Dictionary ([iPhone](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/ponddy-chinese-dictionary/id1569799653)).

**Flashcards and Writing**

- AnkiMobile ([iPhone](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/ankimobile-flashcards/id373493387); $US 24.99) and AnkiDroid ([Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ichi2.anki)) is a popular flashcard tool with many Chinese 'card decks' created by the community.
- [Chinese Peach](https://app.chinesepeach.com) ([iOS](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/chinese-peach/id1533410359); [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chinesepeach)).
- [Chinese Writer](https://www.trainchinese.com/v2/writer.php) ([iOS](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/chinese-writer-by-trainchinese/id422248993); [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.molatra.chinesewriterlite)) provides writing practice by tracing on-screen characters.
- [Daily Chinese](https://www.dailychinese.app/) ([iPhone](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/daily-chinese-flashcards/id1468602303); [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mojayllc.dailychinese)) is a vocabulary builder.
- [Flashonary](http://www.flashonary.com/) ([iOS](https://apps.apple.com/gb/app/flashonary-chinese-english-chinese-german-flashcard/id320888944)) is a flashcard dictionary.
- Inkstone ([Android $US 4.99](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.id126c0rsxlvjwv18cf44u); [demo video](https://www.skishore.me/inkstone/images/demo.gif)) is an app for writing practice.
- [Noodle Chinese](https://www.noodlechinese.com/) ([iPhone](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/noodle-chinese/id1375293467)) is an app for writing practice.
- [Skritter](http://skritter.com/) (iPhone: [old version](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/skritter-chinese/id520277126); [new version](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/skritter-write-chinese/id1370892114); [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.inkren.skritter.chinese&hl=en_US)) is a responsive app for writing practice.  Subscriptions are [$US 14.99 per month](https://legacy.skritter.com/pricing).
- [Sticky Study](http://www.stickystudy.com/chinese.html) ([iPad $US 1.99](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/stickystudy-chinese-hsk-top/id451375935)).
- [trainchinese](https://www.trainchinese.com/) ([iOS](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/trainchinese/id333830076); [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.molatra.trainchinese)).
- [TOFU Learn](https://www.tofulearn.com/) ([iPhone](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tofu-learn/id1298141461); [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tofulearn.tofulearn)) includes character writing practice for Chinese.  It's described as free, but it also has paid "pro" accounts.
- Word Tracer ([iPhone](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/word-tracer-learn-chinese-iphone-edition/id453400918)) provides writing practice by tracing on-screen characters.

**Games**

- 酷狗唱唱 ([iPhone](https://apps.apple.com/cn/app/%E9%85%B7%E7%8B%97%E5%94%B1%E5%94%B1-%E5%85%A8%E6%B0%91%E6%89%8B%E6%9C%BAktv/id1282270796); [QQ](https://a.app.qq.com/o/simple.jsp?pkgname=com.kugou.android.ktvapp)) is a Chinese karaoke app which gives you a score based on your singing.
- NiHao! ([iPad; $US 4.99](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/nihao!/id760028888?mt=8)) grammar and puzzle game.
- Word Swing ([iOS](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/wordswing-chinese/id1277286492); [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wordswing.wordswingchineseapp&hl=en_US)) is a choose-your-own-adventure text adventure game (paid version required for full access).

**General learning**

- AI Super Chinese ([iOS](https://apps.apple.com/uz/app/learn-chinese-ai-super-chinese/id1462500984); [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.superchinese)).
- [Chineasy](https://www.chineasy.com) ([iOS](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/chineasy-cards/id1318941705); [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chineasy.cards&hl=en_US)) is for memorizing characters and basic lessons.
- [ChineseSkill](http://www.chineseskill.com) ([iOS](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/learn-chinese-chineseskill/id777111034); [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chineseskill)) provides learning materials up to HSK4 (speaking, writing, listening and reading), and flash cards.
- Chinesimple HSK (HSK levels: [1](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=es.hskfree.ap), [2](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=es.aroundpixels.hsk2lite), [3](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=es.aroundpixels.hsk3lite), [4](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=es.aroundpixels.hsk4lite), [5](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=es.aroundpixels.hsk5lite)) provides grammar and vocabulary games, a dictionary, and special levels (Android)
- [Dong Chinese](https://www.dong-chinese.com/) ([Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.peterolson.chinse.dongchinese))
- Dot Languages ([iOS](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/dot-languages-learn-chinese/id1547286120); [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dotlanguages.dot&gl=US))
- [Drops](https://languagedrops.com/) ([iOS](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/drops-learn-korean-japanese-chinese-language/id939540371); [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.languagedrops.drops.international)).
- [Duolingo](https://www.duolingo.com/) ([iPhone](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/duolingo-language-lessons/id570060128); [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.duolingo)) is a colorful language-learning app, including Chinese.  Paid versions start at [$US 9.99 per month](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/duolingo-language-lessons/id570060128).
- [HelloChinese](http://www.hellochinese.cc/) ([iPhone](https://apps.apple.com/app/id1001507516); [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hellochinese)) is a beginner app for improving speaking skills based on speech recognition.
- [Incredible Chinese](https://incrediblechinese.com/) ([iOS](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/fluent-academy/id1506535967); [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=academy.fluent.android)) uses AI/speech recognition to learn via Chinese conversations.
- [Lingodeer](https://www.lingodeer.com/) ([iOS](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/lingodeer-learn-languages/id1261193709); [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lingodeer)) has a variety of puzzles for languages including Chinese; paid version [$US 11.99 per month](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/lingodeer-learn-languages/id1261193709).
- [Memrise](https://www.memrise.com/) ([iPhone](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/memrise-ultimate-memorisation/id635966718); [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.memrise.android.memrisecompanion)) is a language memorization app, which includes Chinese.  Subscriptions start at around [$US 8.99 per month](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/memrise-ultimate-memorisation/id635966718).
- [Ninchanese](https://ninchanese.com/) ([Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ninchanese.app)) starts at around [$US 10 per month](https://ninchanese.com/pricing/).
- [Rosetta Stone](https://www.rosettastone.com/) ([iOS](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/rosetta-stone-learn-languages/id435588892); [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=air.com.rosettastone.mobile.CoursePlayer)) is around [$US 9.99 per month](https://www.rosettastone.com/buy-chinese/).
- [Langtern](https://langtern.com) ([iOS](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/id1578011970); [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.langtern.chinese)) has a selection of online material with a popup dictionary, plus learning tools. It's mostly free, with a paid plan of around $US 2 per month.

**Pronunciation**

- [普通话学习](https://apps.apple.com/cn/app/%E6%99%AE%E9%80%9A%E8%AF%9D%E5%AD%A6%E4%B9%A0-%E6%A0%87%E5%87%86%E6%99%AE%E9%80%9A%E8%AF%9D%E5%8F%91%E9%9F%B3%E6%B0%B4%E5%B9%B3%E6%B5%8B%E8%AF%95%E8%BD%AF%E4%BB%B6/id1037958811)
- Cantone ([iOS](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/cantone/id1602297692); [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cantone.cantone))
- Ka ([iOS](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/ka-chinese-tones-learn-pinyin/id6444140899)) is a free, gamified app to learn the tones.

**Reading and Listening**

- [The Chairman's Bao](https://www.thechairmansbao.com/) ([iOS](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/chairmans-bao-learn-chinese/id1074317405); [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uk.co.metapps.thechairmansbao)) is a Chinese graded reader app.  Most content requires a [$US 10 per month subscription](https://www.thechairmansbao.com/my-subscriptions/).
- [Clozemaster](https://www.clozemaster.com/) ([iOS](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/clozemaster/id1149199075); [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.clozemaster.v2)) provides fill-in-the-blank "cloze" sentences in many languages, including Chinese.  ([Pro version: $US 8 per month](https://www.clozemaster.com/pro).)
- [Du Chinese](https://www.duchinese.net/) ([iPhone](https://apps.apple.com/app/du-chinese/id1052961520); [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.sinamon.duchinese)) provides short stories for reading and listening practice (regularly updated; paid version required to access all lessons).
- Hanzi Reader ([iOS](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/hanzi-reader-chinese-dictionary-definitions-displayed/id383433187)) segments Chinese text and allows the user to look up words.
- [M Mandarin](http://funnybean.com) ([iOS](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/m-mandarin-%E6%BC%AB%E4%B8%AD%E6%96%87-learn-chinese/id1202173573); [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.funnybean.mandarin)) teaches Chinese via comics.
- Phrasis ([iOS](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/phrasis/id1557374060)) searches movie subtitles.
- PinyinBrowser ([iOS](http://itunes.apple.com/app/pinyinbrowser/id851303491?uo=5)) adds Pinyin or Bopomofo to Chinese web pages while you browse.
- Pinyiner Free ([Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.astratech.chinesereader_free)) for pinyin annotation of copied text or books.
- [Readibu - Chinese novel reader](https://www.readibu.com/) ([iPhone](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/readibu-chinese-novel-reader/id1474518982); $US 4.99 per month; [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.readibu.mobile&pcampaignid=MKT-Other-global-all-co-prtnr-py-PartBadge-Mar2515-1)).
- Wise Talk ([iPhone](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/wise-talk/id854767124)) provides idioms for listening practice (paid version $US 0.99).

**Translations and OCR**

- [Baidu Translate](https://fanyi.baidu.com/) (百度翻译) ([iOS](https://apps.apple.com/cn/app/bai-du-fan-yi-baidu-translate/id605670941)) provides Chinese-to-English, English-to-Chinese translations, OCR (in-app purchase in Pleco), common phrases/expressions list, audio lookup, etc.
- [Baidu Chinese](https://dict.baidu.com/) (百度汉语) ([iPhone](https://apps.apple.com/cn/app/%E7%99%BE%E5%BA%A6%E6%B1%89%E8%AF%AD-%E8%AE%A9%E6%B1%89%E8%AF%AD%E5%AD%A6%E4%B9%A0%E6%9B%B4%E7%AE%80%E5%8D%95/id1065829176)) provides free OCR, compositions (作文), and Chinese poetry recital.
- [Google Assistant](https://assistant.google.com/) ([iOS](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/google-assistant/id1220976145); [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.googleassistant)) has an [interpreter mode](https://support.google.com/googlenest/answer/9234753) which live translates conversations.

Comment: There used to be a reading app known as [Decipher](http://app.decipherchinese.com/new) but I think it has aged away.  The website has some remaining parts.

Comment: Incredible Chinese is now called [Polyvox](https://polyvox.app) and is available on the [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app.polyvox.polyvox_app) and [App Store](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/polyvox-mandarin-chinese/id6450912702?platform=iphone)

Answer (score 18):

### Podcasts

You can find many such podcasts by searching for `Chinese` on e.g. [Spotify](https://www.google.com/search?&q=site%3Aopen.spotify.com%20chinese) or [Tune In](https://tunein.com/search/?query=chinese)

- [ChinesePod](http://chinesepod.com/) has many Chinese lessons, starting at around [$US 14 per month](https://www.chinesepod.com/pricing).
- [Coffee Break Chinese](https://radiolingua.com/coffeebreakchinese/); transcript requires paid account, starting at [£96 once-off](https://radiolingua.com/coffeebreakchinese/).
- [Hacking Chinese](https://www.hackingchinese.com/podcast/)
- [I Love Learning Chinese](https://ilovelearningchinese.com/)
- [Popup Chinese](http://popupchinese.com/)
- [Player.FM](https://zh.player.fm) has a variety of Chinese podcasts.
- [Learning Chinese through Stories](https://learningchinesethroughstories.com/)
- [每日视频新闻](http://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/mei-ri-shi-pin-xin-wen/id297394794) video podcast news.
- [Melnyks](https://www.melnyks.com/learn-chinese/) (also at [Tune In](https://tunein.com/podcasts/Educational/Learn-Chinese---Easy-Situational-Mandarin-Chinese--p886447/))
- [Radio Garden](https://radio.garden/) enables listening to radio worldwide, including Chinese radio, e.g. [Joy FM](http://radio.garden/listen/beijing-joy-radio-87-6-fm/Ts6_sOlz) (Beijing) and [Kiss Radio](http://radio.garden/listen/kissradio-fm-99-9/zD7B9jSe) (Taiwan).
- [Speak Chinese Naturally](https://speakchinesenaturally.com/); transcript requires paid account, starting at [$US 3.99 per month](https://speakchinesenaturally.com/join-us-2/).
- [Talk Chineasy](https://www.chineasy.com/talk/)
- [The Unemployable](https://theue.firstory.io/)
- [You Can Learn Chinese](https://youcanlearnchinese.mandarincompanion.com/)

(YouTube channels are listed under [social media](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/1120/resources-for-learning-mandarin-chinese/17648#17648).)

Answer (score 16):

### Online Courses

- [ChineseFor.Us](https://chinesefor.us/) is a video course (around [$US 9.99 per month](https://chinesefor.us/pricing)).
- [Chinese Learn Online](http://www.chineselearnonline.com) is an audio course taught from Taiwan; paid account (starting at [$US 19.95 per month](https://www.chineselearnonline.com/amember/signup/signup_2020may)) required for transcript, etc.
- [Chinese Zero to Hero](https://chinesezerotohero.teachable.com/) is a video course based on the HSK (sample videos are on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCQ3IlLg5VGeydxtswBoyt6A)); bundle price varies e.g. $US 29 for HSK1.
- [Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/courses?query=chinese) includes many free Chinese courses, such as Chinese for HSK [1](https://www.coursera.org/learn/hsk-1), [2](https://www.coursera.org/learn/hsk-2), [3](https://www.coursera.org/learn/hsk-3-part2), [4](https://www.coursera.org/learn/hsk-4), [5](https://www.coursera.org/learn/chinese-for-hsk5), [6](https://www.coursera.org/learn/chinese-for-hsk-6) (payment required for course verification).
- [Culture Alley](http://culturealley.com/mandarin) provides free language conversations and games, and includes Mandarin; paid expert help.
- [MandarinX](https://www.edx.org/school/mandarinx) provides free online courses such as "Mandarin Chinese Essentials" and "Mandarin Chinese for Business" (course verification costs $US 99).
- [Melnyks](http://www.melnyks.com/) provides Chinese audio lessons; paid account (starting at [$US 97 per year](https://www.melnyks.com/amember/signup)) required for transcript, etc.
- [Outlier Chinese Character Masterclass](https://www.outlier-linguistics.com/products/how-to-learn-chinese-characters) provides instruction on character components, etc., for $US 99.00.
- [Popup Chinese](http://popupchinese.com/) provides Chinese lessons via podcasts; paid account ([$US 99.99 per year](http://popupchinese.com/account)) required for mp3, transcript, etc.
- [Yoyo Chinese](http://yoyochinese.com) provides video lessons, etc.; starts at around [$US 88](https://yoyochinese.com/store) per bundle.

### Tutors

- [Berlitz](https://www.berlitz.com/) provides a range of [Mandarin classes](https://www.berlitz.com/languages/mandarin); pricing is not immediately available on their website.
- [Instant Mandarin](https://instantmandarin.com) provides 1-on-1 online courses; bundles start with 12 lessons at [$US 120](https://instantmandarin.com/pricing).
- [Lingo Bus](https://www.lingobus.com) provides online 1-on-1 tutoring and group classes for children aged 4-15, and they have been running for 5 years.
- [LTL Mandarin](https://ltl-beijing.com/) provides a variety of tutoring methods; with pricing in the ballpark of [￥150 per hour](https://ltl-beijing.com/chinese-tutor-beijing/).
- [Mandarin Zone](http://www.mandarinzone.com/) has both 1-on-1 lessons and group classes.
- [That's Mandarin](https://thatsmandarin.com/) provides a variety of tutoring and learning methods, with pricing at [￥84+ per hour](https://www.thatsmandarin.com/course/online/small-group-chinese-classes/) for group classes and [￥165+ per hour](https://www.thatsmandarin.com/course/online/private-chinese-classes/) for 1-on-1 lessons.

Answer (score 15):

### Textbooks

See also [Chinese textbook grammar index](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Chinese_textbook_grammar_index) at the Chinese Grammar Wiki.

**Learning**

- Yong Ho, *Beginner's Chinese*, 2010.  [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0781812577).
- ShaoLan. *Chineasy Everyday: Learning Chinese Through Its Culture*, 2016.  [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0062439715).  (Now [available as an app](https://www.chineasy.com)).
- Kan Qian, *Colloquial Chinese: The Complete Course for Beginners*, 2015.  [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1138958271).  Texts, exercises, grammar highlights, etc.
- Jiang Liping, *HSK Standard Course (HSK标准教程)*, ~2018.  Amazon: HSK [1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07PRPG8QV); [2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07PNSZSYZ); [3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07PMV711L); [4上](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07PQZZ16F); [4下](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07PMVPFDT)；[5上 and 5下](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07RGSRZJ7); [6上](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/7561942540) and [6下](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01MY6TUTQ).  Answers are available from [BLCUP](https://www.blcup.com/EnRes/), specifically [1](https://www.blcup.com/EnRes/ResInfo?rid=43618#001); [2](https://www.blcup.com/EnRes/ResInfo?rid=43619#001); [3](https://www.blcup.com/EnRes/ResInfo?rid=43620#001); [4上](https://www.blcup.com/EnRes/ResInfo?rid=43621#001); [4下](https://www.blcup.com/EnRes/ResInfo?rid=43622#001); [5上](https://www.blcup.com/EnRes/ResInfo?rid=43623#001); [5下](https://www.blcup.com/EnRes/ResInfo?rid=43624#001); [6上](https://www.blcup.com/EnRes/ResInfo?rid=43625#001); [6下](https://www.blcup.com/enres/ResInfo?rid=51694#001).  The workbook answers are available from [1](https://www.blcup.com/EnRes/ResInfo?rid=10382#001); [2](https://www.blcup.com/EnRes/ResInfo?rid=10383#001); [3](https://www.blcup.com/EnRes/ResInfo?rid=10384#001); [4上](https://www.blcup.com/EnRes/ResInfo?rid=11444#001); [4下](https://www.blcup.com/EnRes/ResInfo?rid=11552#001); [5上](https://www.blcup.com/EnRes/ResInfo?rid=58147#001); [5下](https://www.blcup.com/EnRes/ResInfo?rid=58148#001); [6上](https://www.blcup.com/enres/ResInfo?rid=58149#001); [6下](https://www.blcup.com/enres/ResInfo?rid=50295#001).
- Yuehua Liu et al., *Integrated Chinese: Simplified Characters Textbook, Level 1, Part 1 中文听说读写*, 2008. [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0887276385); [Cheng & Tsui](http://www.cheng-tsui.com/store/products/integrated_chinese).
- Yong Ho, *Intermediate Chinese*, 2013.  [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0781813115).
- Peking University, *Modern Chinese: A Basic Course*, 1971.  [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486227553).
- Liu Xun, *New Practical Chinese Reader*, 2004. [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/7561910401).
- James W. Heisig and Timothy W. Richardson, *Remembering Traditional Hanzi*  and *Remembering Simplified Hanzi*, 2008+.  Amazon: [T1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0824833244), [T2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0824836561); [S1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0824833236), [S1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0824836553); Nanzan [T1](http://nirc.nanzan-u.ac.jp/en/publications/miscellaneous-publications/remembering-hanzi-1/), [T2](http://nirc.nanzan-u.ac.jp/en/publications/miscellaneous-publications/remembering-traditional-hanzi-ii/); [S1](http://nirc.nanzan-u.ac.jp/en/publications/miscellaneous-publications/remembering-hanzi/), [S2](http://nirc.nanzan-u.ac.jp/en/publications/miscellaneous-publications/remembering-simplified-hanzi-ii/).  A method for memorizing Chinese characters without their pronunciation.  (See also: [a fan-made dataset](https://www.plecoforums.com/threads/heisigs-remembering-simplified-hanzi-1-2.3114/) for simplified characters.)
- Yuonne Li Walls and Jan W. Walls, *Using Chinese - A guide to contemporary usage*, 2009.  [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00QIT3OBE).

**Reference**

- Muhammad Wolfgang G. A. Schmidt, *All the Grammar and Language Points For Each Of The Six Levels of the Chinese Language Proficiency Test (HSK)*, 2018.  [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3959354738).
- Yip Po-Ching and Dan Rimmington, *Chinese - An Essential Grammar*, 2006.  [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0415372615).
- Charles N. Li and Sandra A. Thompson, *Mandarin Chinese: A Functional Reference Grammar*, 1989.  [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0520066103); [Google Books](https://books.google.com/books/about/Mandarin_Chinese.html?id=njea2LBW4jcC).  Only pinyin (no characters).
- Claudia Ross and Jing-heng Sheng Ma, *Modern Mandarin Chinese Grammar: A Practical Guide (Modern Grammars)*, 2014.  [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0415827140).
- Dejin Li and Meizhen Cheng, *A Practical Chinese Grammar for Foreigners (外国人实用汉语语法)*, 2008.  [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/7561921632).  Bilingual (English and Chinese); characters only.
- Claudia Ross, *Schaum's Outline of Chinese Grammar*, 2004.  [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071635262).

Answer (score 12):

### Dictionaries

**Online**

- [Almaany](https://www.almaany.com/en/dict/en-zh/)
- [CantoDict](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/scripts/wordlist.htm) includes Mandarin.
- [潮州音字典](http://www.czyzd.com/) is a pinyin based dictionary.
- [Chinese Tutor Dictionary](http://www.fastchinese.org/dictionary)
- [Collins Mandarin Chinese Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/chinese-english)
- [Collocation Search](http://cca.xingtanlu.cn/)
- [Dict.cn](http://dict.cn/)
- [Forvo](https://forvo.com/languages/zh/) pronunciation dictionary.
- [HanDian (汉典)](http://zdic.net) (zdic)
- [HanziCraft](https://hanzicraft.com/) character dictionary.
- [Linguee](https://cn.linguee.com/%E4%B8%AD%E6%96%87-%E8%8B%B1%E8%AF%AD)
- [MDBG English-Chinese](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary) Online dictionary website based on CC-CEDICT
- [Mo eDict](https://www.moedict.tw)
- [Revised Taiwan Academic Online Dictionary 重編國語辭典修訂本](http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cbdic/search.htm)
- [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/)
- [WordBuddy Dictionary](https://www.wordbuddy.com/pages/dictionary/dictionarysearch.php?&force=1&search_type=a&search_words=nihao)
- [Xiaoma Cidian (小马词典)](http://www.xiaoma.info/)
- [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php)
- [Youdao](http://dict.youdao.com/)
- [在线汉语词典](http://xh.5156edu.com/)

Image search provided by [Baidu](https://image.baidu.com), [Bing](http://www.bing.com/Images), and [Google](https://images.google.com/) can be used as a visual dictionary.  Many dictionaries are listed at [Dictionaryphile](https://github.com/Dictionaryphile/All_Dictionaries).

***Removed items***

- <s>Bkrs (mostly in Russian)</s>  (removed for copyright reasons, see comments to the answer [here](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/30478/bkrs-chinese-dictionary)).
- <strike>[nciku](http://www.nciku.com)</strike> [Line Dict](http://www.linedict.com/dict.html#/cnen/)

**Technical**

- [Chinese Medicinal Material Images Database](https://library.hkbu.edu.hk/electronic/libdbs/mmd/)
- [cosdna.com](http://cosdna.com/) for chemistry and cosmetics
- [Dr. Dict](http://www.drdict.com) medical dictionary.
- [SciDict](http://www.scidict.org/) for science, biomedical, mechanics, chemistry and computer science.

**Offline**

- ABC dictionary - available as a paid-for add-on in [Pleco](https://www.pleco.com/). Gives parts of speech and rates homonyms by frequency of usage. See also [this answer](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/41195/2508).
- Hanping Chinese Dictionary Pro 汉英词典 ([Android; $US 2.99](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.embermitre.hanping.app.pro)).
- [Pleco](https://www.pleco.com/) ([iOS](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/pleco-chinese-dictionary/id341922306); [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pleco.chinesesystem)) free dictionary with example sentences; many additional features e.g. OCR via in-app purchases.
- [Wenlin](http://www.wenlin.com/).  Non-introductory versions start at [$US 2.99 per month](https://wenlinshangdian.com/).

Many dictionaries are downloadable from [HuZheng.org](http://download.huzheng.org/zh_CN/).

**Downloadable plain text files**

- [CC-CEDICT](http://simonwiles.net/projects/cc-cedict/) ([Wiki](https://cc-cedict.org/wiki/))  online, downloadable (as opposed to searchable-only) public-domain Chinese-English dictionary
- [SUBTLEX-CH](http://crr.ugent.be/programs-data/subtitle-frequencies/subtlex-ch): Chinese Word and Character Frequencies
  Based on Film Subtitles. Includes part-of-speech information.

Answer (score 11):

### News

- Australian [ABC中文](https://www.abc.net.au/news/chinese/) News.
- [The Australian](https://cn.theaustralian.com.au/)
- BBC News中文: [simplified](https://www.bbc.com/zhongwen/simp) and [traditional](https://www.bbc.com/zhongwen/trad).
- [China Central Television (CCTV / 中国中央电视台)](https://tv.cctv.com/live/) live stream.
- [FT中文网 - Financial Times Chinese](http://www.ftchinese.com/)
- [Helsinki Times](https://cn.helsinkitimes.fi/)
- [MSN News](https://www.msn.cn/zh-cn) has Chinese-English bilingual articles labelled 双语.
- [纽约时报中文网 - New York Times](http://cn.nytimes.com/): English-Chinese parallel text.
- [SBS News Mandarin](https://www.sbs.com.au/language/mandarin) (and [audio podcast](https://www.sbs.com.au/language/mandarin)).
- [Sina新闻中心](https://news.sina.com.cn/)
- [中国日报网](http://www.chinadaily.com.cn/): China Daily ([bilingual](https://language.chinadaily.com.cn/news_bilingual/)).

Answer (score 10):

### Books

**Graded readers**

- [Chinese Breeze](http://www.chinesebreeze.net/) series.
- [Imagin8](https://imagin8press.com/) series.
- [Sinolingua](http://www.sinolingua.com.cn/index.php) series.
- [Mandarin Companion](https://mandarincompanion.com/) series (simplified and traditional).
- [Tales and Traditions](https://www.cheng-tsui.com/browse/tales-and-traditions) series at Cheng & Tsui.
- [BLCUP Graded Readers](https://blcup.com/EnSeriesBook/index/1636) series (simplified).

(Note: Fig. 7 in [*Loach* (2017)](http://www.jamesloach.com/papers/readability.pdf) analyzes the difficulty of Mandarin Companion and Sinolingua.)

**Novels**

- [活着 (To Live)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/To_Live_(novel)).

Also note [a Reddit /r/chinesebookclub post](https://www.reddit.com/r/chinesebookclub/comments/5pb4yx/corpus_of_chinese_novels_sorted_by_difficulty/) sorts Chinese novels by difficulty ([results](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/brendan-t/haodoo/master/haodoo-books.org)).  The YouTube channel [Kuo’s Audiobooks](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCJxNLvWAnazm1w-EKoo7Z_Q) has readings of Harry Potter novels.

Answer (score 9):

### Social Media

**Discord**

- [30 Days of Chinese](https://discord.gg/GyaY2PX) is for sharing your Chinese studies.
- [Reddit r/ChineseLanguage](https://discord.gg/G4nagat)

**Facebook**

- [Business Chinese Learning](https://www.facebook.com/businesschineselearning)
- [CCTV中文](https://www.facebook.com/CCTV.CH) Chinese news.
- [Chinese Class 101](https://www.facebook.com/ChineseClass101/)
- [CRI Learn Chinese](https://www.facebook.com/crilearnchinese/)
- [Hanbridge Mandarin Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/HangridgeMandarin)
- [Learn Chinese characters](https://www.facebook.com/chinesecharacterslearning/?fref=ts&ref=br_tf)
- Learn Chinese Mandarin [HSK1](https://www.facebook.com/groups/294971488137057/) [HSK2](https://www.facebook.com/groups/680764145797105/) [HSK3](https://www.facebook.com/groups/847553949046831/) [HSK4](https://www.facebook.com/groups/267659047538214/) [HSK5](https://www.facebook.com/groups/536408247293302/) [HSK6](https://www.facebook.com/groups/224576495512293/) with Richard Wu.

**Twitter**

- [AllSet Learning](https://twitter.com/allsetlearning)
- [Hacking Chinese](https://twitter.com/HackingChinese)
- [HSK Official](https://twitter.com/HSKTestOfficial)
- [Skritter](https://twitter.com/SkritterHQ)

**YouTube channels** (native content useful for learners)

- [备胎说车](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC7RL3bksyvu7rH7T6KFFkjw) (cars)
- [Hello Catie](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCxls4ftUSbEcrDR1zQWIwfA) (fashion, makeup, shopping)
- [黃瑽寧醫師健康講堂](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCkha3wg7As4t9duOzre5HcQ) (Doctor Huang Congning)
- [李永乐老师](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCSs4A6HYKmHA2MG_0z-F0xw) (Teacher Li Yongle)
- [科普记](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCo0wi08hNwwAUpyZ_p6eX-g) (popular science)
- [科学声音](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCUBhobCkTLhgfUNRAgHSYmw) (Voice of Science)
- [妈咪说MommyTalk](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCLROLAN8kmU7tGQDs6KH-bQ) (popular science)
- [TEDxTaipei](https://www.youtube.com/user/TEDxTaipei)
- [樱桃小丸子 动漫 中文版](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UClHebX3GBL9lzvH_eJB_7iw) (Chibi Maruko-chan, children's anime)
- [小猪佩奇](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCRi0sw4PDw-C2C7fS9hrx5Q) (Peppa Pig)
- [Yan Talk](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCwNGgFvBpxtU8JagZLzztzQ)
- [一席YiXi](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCKFB_rVEFEF3l-onQGvGx1A) (similar to TEDx)

**YouTube channels** (teaching)

- [Ansami App](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCDljsALKtxMvhmvs3PP3guw)
- [Carly LetsSpeakXYZ](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCD8mCDvxGYJXl50GddxhKBw)
- [ChineseEddieG汉语艾迪](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCXNTChai4lWB_2B8K_a2bKA)
- [ChinesePod](https://www.youtube.com/user/ChinesePodTV)
- [Chinesewithmei Everyday](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCF2GCj_xOYvlU2cztE85qjw)
- [Chinese Zero to Hero](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCQ3IlLg5VGeydxtswBoyt6A)
- [Easy Chinese](https://www.youtube.com/user/haiya8891)
- [Easy Mandarin with Li Can](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCKbBU7zv0PUdOMxPnenl_zg)
- [Everyday Chinese](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCSXriUqkzZmAQklQ0N9XFVw)
- [Fragrant Mandarin 香橘子](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCVk35GjhYmoupCwWbaag1FA)
- [Grace Mandarin Chinese](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCC_fdR7zZ_5SU--xuOrEdKw)
- [Hancai Chinese](https://www.youtube.com/c/HancaiChinese)
- [HSK Tips](https://www.youtube.com/c/hsktips)
- [Kid learning Chinese/Mandarin 孩子学中文](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC_0oPrCShB7ZzBk4D66FHSw)
- [LANGUAGE ch 中国語](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=&list=UUbK-aV96Y4vb5sklvZr1T1Q)
- [Mandarin Blueprint](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCc5ueW8aqO73Q6MevB8L5PA)
- [Mandarin Click](https://www.youtube.com/c/MandarinClick)
- [Mandarin Corner](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC2fAiRQHRQT9aj9P_ijYeow)
- [Masterchinesewithpeipei](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCbOWEw21I45ZZxBlpANA-Xw)
- [每日中文课Free To Learn](https://www.youtube.com/c/DANLIAOFreeToLearn)
- [PeggyTeachesChinese](https://www.youtube.com/user/PeggyTeachesChinese)
- [Peter Hanyu](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCrLkNik3JQCZuqTj78fJDEg)
- [可可读课本 Keke Reading](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCN0K3i_53N9F-IicqHXSY6Q)
- [Richard Chinese Language](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCCQmKxqC9h8OknMgw4_Jsqw)
- [ShuoshuoChinese说说中文](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC_Aiv9xguPQxZ6msnNoz3HQ)
- [Startalk Mandarin](https://www.youtube.com/@startalkmandarin)
- [大鹏说中文 Speak Chinese with Da Peng](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCNmZr4WBw71bdJYjaycLodA)
- [SyS Mandarin](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCUjFsQAUUS1IFM7oyUXeB1g)
- [Talk Taiwanese Mandarin With Abby](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCSoH-pm1Rto-1-ls5iKsQFg/featured)
- [YMC Learn Chinese](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCye2eRed9pzbORP-KnwF8TQ)

In addition to YouTube, there is also [Bilibili](https://www.bilibili.com/), [iQiYi](https://www.iqiyi.com/), [iXiGua](https://www.ixigua.com/), [TuDou](https://www.tudou.com/), and [YouKu](https://www.youku.com/).

Answer (score 6):

### Lists of Resources

- [Awesome Chinese NLP](https://github.com/crownpku/Awesome-Chinese-NLP) lists Chinese natural language processing resources.
- [Chinese Discord Resource](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vTnqyjv--iUkCnD7BBCUpDjKCOgXgPPdUtP1hSk8RtzaDE8ciQfDQzmS6illkN2fNUqVsIFBI8t_LCq/pubhtml) for the [看剧学汉语 Discord](https://discord.com/channels/721751244041093150/722713696044056597): TV shows sources; listening; reading; TV show recommendations; game recommendations.
- [Chinese-English Exchange Discord Server Resource List](https://espaspw.github.io/Resource-Guide/#All)
- Chinese Grammar Wiki's [textbook index](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Chinese_textbook_grammar_index).
- Chinese Zero to Hero [resources](https://www.zerotohero.ca/#/en/zh/resource/list/all/all).
- [Dictionaryphile](https://github.com/Dictionaryphile/All_Dictionaries) lists dictionaries.
- [Graded readers, by the numbers](https://www.chinese-forums.com/forums/topic/44336-graded-readers-by-the-numbers-characterswords-page-count/) lists graded readers and their statistics.
- [Graded Watching](http://www.jiong3.com/gradedwatching/) ranks movies and TV series in terms of difficulty.
- [Gratis Global](http://gratisglobal.com/learn-chinese-free/) lists free resources.
- [Hacking Chinese](https://challenges.hackingchinese.com/resources) for resource reviews.
- Heavenly Path's [reading guide](https://heavenlypath.notion.site/Comprehensive-Reading-Guide-From-beginner-to-native-novels-b3d6abd583a944a397b4fbbb81e0c38c), and list of [web novels](https://heavenlypath.notion.site/Webnovels-and-Books-29ee006777bd4d9fbbd0ea5eb29ec514).
- Heavenly Path's [listening guide](https://heavenlypath.notion.site/Comprehensive-Listening-Guide-from-Beginner-to-Native-Media-42700b5402ce47d7b5209d4dc50d0cef).
- [Learn Chinese Club](https://learnchinese.club/) for YouTube videos.
- Lindie Botes (polyglot) lists the [resources she uses](https://lindiebotes.com/chinese-resources/).
- [Memrise](https://community.memrise.com/t/wiki-lets-create-a-nice-resources-list-mandarin-chinese/162)
- [Reddit's r/ChineseLanguage resource flair](https://www.reddit.com/r/ChineseLanguage/search/?q=flair%3Aresources&source=recent&restrict_sr=1&sort=top)
- [YouTube channels to learn Chinese](https://www.wordlab.app/catalogue/youtube/chinese.html)
- [WordReference "Resources" thread](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/resources.533726/)

Answer (score 4):

## Online Tests

**How many characters do I know?**

- [Clavas Sinica](http://www.clavisinica.com/character-test.html)
- [Quick Test](https://chinesepedia.herokuapp.com/test) at Chinesepedia.
- [汉语识字量测试](https://www.arealme.com/how-many-chinese-characters-do-i-know/cn/)
- [HanziShan](http://hanzishan.com/)
- [hanzi.sjz.io](http://hanzi.sjz.io/#/words)
- [Hanzi Quest](https://hanzi-quest.netlify.app/)
- [Hanzi Test](http://hanzitest.herokuapp.com/) by @ericrjiang.
- [HSK Level](https://www.hsklevel.com/) (includes HSK 3.0)
- [Word Swing](https://wordswing.com/how-many-characters-do-you-know/instructions)
- [zhtoolkit](http://www.zhtoolkit.com/apps/wordtest/)

**How many words do I know?**

- [17 Minute Languages](https://www.17-minute-languages.com/en/Chinese-placement-test/)
- [HSK Level](https://www.hsklevel.com/) (includes HSK 3.0)
- [中文词汇量测试](https://www.arealme.cn/chinese-vocabulary-size-test/cn/)

**How many chengyu do I know?**

- [HSK Level](https://www.hsklevel.com/)

**How fast can I read?**

- [阅读速度测试](http://www.zhongguosou.com/zonghe/yueDuSuDuCeShi.aspx) by 众果搜

Answer (score 2):

### AI chat bots

Note: some of these are merely different interfaces for ChatGPT; some of these are paid services; the Chinese services likely require a Chinese ID or phone number; many are unavailable in various locations.

- [AnonChatGPT](https://anonchatgpt.com/)
- [ChatArt](https://www.imyfone.com/chat-ai/) (by iMyFone)
- [Character.ai](https://beta.character.ai/) (beta) has many Chinese-speaking bots, such as Chinese teachers by [@jeffh](https://c.ai/c/s6ZpWy629kcqPezBFyrBzdyKE_4uALQQTK1h771r0o4) and [@lieyanqzu](https://c.ai/c/lmN7Du14GLz4WKIYOjqaEpHxt4YyOzLlLddpbiSSJ9E)
- [ChatGLM](https://chatglm.cn) (by Tsinghua researchers)
- [ChatGPT](https://chat.openai.com/) (by OpenAI)
- [Free ChatGPT](https://vitalentum.net/free-chat-gpt)
- [Gemini](https://gemini.google.com/) (by Google; formerly Bard)
- [HeyPi](https://heypi.com/talk)
- [HuggingChat](https://huggingface.co/chat/)
- [KoalaChat](https://koala.sh/chat)
- [MyShell.AI](https://app.myshell.ai/explore); go to "Explore/More" to filter by languages
- [Ora.ai](https://ora.ai/chatbot-master/openai-chatgpt-chatbot)
- Poe.com (by Quora): [Assistant](https://poe.com/Assistant) ("Good in languages other than English"; formerly called Sage) and [ChatGPT](https://poe.com/ChatGPT).
- [polyglot](https://github.com/liou666/polyglot), downloadable for Mac and Windows.
- Snapchat My AI (based on ChatGPT), comes with the Snapchat app ([Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.snapchat.android&hl=en_US); [iPhone](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/snapchat/id447188370)).
- [通义千问](https://qianwen.aliyun.com) (by Alibaba)
- [文心一言](https://yiyan.baidu.com/) (Ernie Bot, by Baidu), requires a Chinese ID card to register
- [小冰](https://www.xiaoice.com/) (Xiaoice, by Microsoft [somewhat historical nowadays])
- [YouChat](https://you.com/search?tbm=youchat)

There's also [Bing Chat](https://bing.com/chat) and [MOSS](https://moss.fastnlp.top/) which I haven't gotten working yet.

There's many other AIs which output Chinese (too many to list).  Many of which are not especially useful.

[Visual-GLM](https://huggingface.co/spaces/lykeven/visualglm-6b) can generate Chinese text given an image and a prompt.

##### Designed for language learners (includes Mandarin)

- [LangoTalk](https://www.langotalk.org/)
- MemBot (part of [Memrise](https://www.memrise.com/))
- [Practice a Language](https://practicealanguage.xyz/)
- [Talkpal.ai](https://talkpal.ai)
- [Univerbal](https://www.univerbal.app/) (formerly Quazel)