# Website or tools that puts pinyin on top or bottom of the characters automatically

Tags: pinyin, resources, websites

Are there any websites or tools that will put pinyin on top or bottom of the characters automatically?

Comment: What do you mean by "puts"? You're looking at a random Chinese webpage in a brower and you want Pinyin added over all Chinese text? You're making a document in HTML or some other format and want Pinyin to automatically appear over the Chinese Characters you enter? etc etc etc ...

Comment: http://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/1325/3561 Chrome & Firefox plugins that, on hover, will display pinyin and meaning.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of the linked question. I am not trying to use this to learn Chinese. This is more about printing out a handout with Chinese and pinyin on top of each character to use to teach other people Chinese or just to help people who is not good at reading characters (like how beginner's textbook usually does).

Comment: Slightly related and disclaimer that I'm the creator of what I'm about to suggest: there's an Angular library that allows websites to generate pinyin (on top or below) chinese characters.  It requires the website itself to embed it so it's not for end users I'm afraid.  https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-piao-liang-hanzi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never looked for this kind of a tool before - good idea! I just ran a search using  and came across an online tool that will do what you ask:

http://zhongwenzhuanpinyin.51240.com/

If you can read a little bit of Chinese, I would recommend trying this one. It will convert your Chinese characters to pinyin and show tones.

I have read on many Chinese website that there is a way to do all of this with Word but I am not familiar enough with this. You can get the basic idea here:

http://office.wps.cn/wpsword/21508-2013-04-10-16-44-20-302.html

Hopefully someone else will be able to explain how that works in more detail.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. Your link to get this working in Word is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

google translate will do this now.
Though this is notoriously hard to do. there are many many research papers on this. So keep in mind that it won't always be correct.

[translate.google.com](http://translate.google.com)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I believe this tool does what you're requesting.

http://www.standardmandarin.com/chinese-pinyin-annotation

It even allows you to automatically add English definitions on top, giving you a sort of 3-line interlinear version.

The output has also been designed to be print-ready, if that is relevant to you.