# Videos for learning Chinese Mandarin

Tags: resources, learning

I am well aware there of posts such as [this](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/1120/resources-for-learning-mandarin-chinese), but I am specifically looking for videos that would be on youtube, for example. There are many videos on youtube, but I have been able to find anything that is like a lecture. I have only been able to find short videos here and there, but nothing that follows some sort of syllabus (lesson 1, 2, 3, etc.). Are there any such resources?

Comment: Have you tried to filter your results by playlist?

Answer (score 1):

As what you said, Television also helps you that have all been in your seen post:

CCTV 4 (mms://8.3.230.132/cctv-4/cctvNews01.wmv)
NJTV 1 - Nanjing TV (mms://218.94.122.203/njtvxw)
XZTV1* (mms://218.3.205.21/xwzhpd)
XZTV2* (mms://218.3.205.21/jjshpd)
XZTV3* (mms://218.3.205.21/shzfpd)
NYTV - Nanyang TV (mms://61.136.113.41/nytv_1)

Besides, you can also see this:

[快乐汉语](http://cctv.cntv.cn/lm/kuailehanyu/index.shtml)

[跟我学汉语](http://english.cntv.cn/learnchinese/)

Answer (score -2):

environment is the most important. buy a ticket and fly to China, rare a house and then you would learn Chinese in 6 months. ( in Beijing, you can rare a house at $500 ~ $1000 per month )

but, I suggest you first of all have the basics of Chinese, such as: pronouciatin, the gramma, and learn more than 2000 characters.

don't study from CCTV news... even we Chinese people can not understand some of the them, such as: '一手抓农业结构的战略性调整'... '大力开展。。。把XX政策落实到实处'...

Comment: Buying a ticket and moving to China isn't very practical