# I Want to Switch Baidu to Pinyin from Simplified

Tags: mandarin, pinyin

I am a new student to learning Chinese and am having quite the problem using the internet. I am learning pinyin first and am wondering how I can change my Baidu account to pinyin from simplified.

Cheers,
Matt

Comment: Check here:
http://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/5841/tool-which-can-convert-web-pages-from-hanzi-to-either-pinyin-or-zhuyin-fuhao

Comment: I realize now that the question didn't make sense, I answered this question to the best of my abilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading around I realized my error. There are some browser addons that display the Pinyin but I had assumed wrong. Pinying is mostly used for pronunciation and typing but Chinese sites like Baidu normally display in simplified and there is no way to switch them. Simplified is for reading.

Hopes this helps anyone from feeling as dumb as me.