# Keeping track of words learned

Tags: resources

I'm looking for a good online site to keep track of chinese words I've learned. I've looked at memrise.com, but found it lacking in features since its not linked to a dictionary and I have to manually enter character, pinyin and english. I've also looked at http://www.nciku.com/ which seems to has a nice vocabulary list which is integrated with their dictionary. Both of these sites also has the ability to generate "tests" for you to help you test and remember things you've learned in the past.

Are there any other options available out there? What are you guys using?

谢谢

Jaco

Comment: Not sure if this is a good place for resource Q&A. A quick search shows this resource-type question has been answered before on this site (http://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/1120/resources-for-learning-mandarin-chinese/6780#6780). On my iPhone, I use Pleco and it's many add-on's to read and save word lists, and documents. I also use a couple of apps I built for the iPhone/iPad (on profile). I try to learn characters solely and also in context, for example using idioms or in an interesting book, which helps memorisation.

Comment: Voted to close as 'looking for learning resources'

Answer (score 3):

I think a close search of the SE site is what's called for here. Doing so I was able to find a link to Yellowbridge.com and it's memory game (an alternative to flash cards). http://www.yellowbridge.com/chinese/mtch-options.php?deck=ic-1-1. There are other websites like http://lingomi.com and http://zhongwen.com that may prove useful.  Chinesetools.com is another. A Google search will yield many more.

Answer (score 1):

## Skritter

Learn vocab and hand writing at the same time, while keeping track of your vocabulary.