# I would like to learn common greetings in Chinese

Tags: greetings

I would like to learn common greetings in Chinese. I haven't taken any classes or used any textbooks. I would like to learn, very much! So I would be able to carry on simple conversation with Chinese friends :)

thank you

Comment: Welcome to the site. Here is a [question with 12 answers](http://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/1120/resources-for-learning-mandarin-chinese) for resources you can use to get started. You can also use the links others provided in the comments. What you do after that will be very helpful. I suggest you read through the material and then either change this question to something not already present on the site or just delete it and post a new question (I am sure you will have many of those). Good luck getting started and enjoy learning Chinese 

Comment: Please share your research

Answer (score 2):

believe or not, they may say hello.
If it's some good friend, maybe their nick name.

Answer (score 1):

36 phrases to say hello in Chinese - audio in link.

http://chinesespeak.com/hello-chinese/

Saying hello

1. 你好！
   Pinyin: nǐ hǎo！ 
   Meaning: Hello.
2. 您好！
   Pinyin: nín hǎo！
   Meaning: Hello. Used when addressing seniors or superiors to show respect.

Time-based greetings

1. 早上好！
   Pinyin: zǎo shang hǎo！
   Meaning: Good morning!
2. 早安
   Pinyin: zǎo ān
   Meaning: Good morning . Literally “Peace at morning”
3. 早
   Pinyin: zǎo 
   Meaning: Morning!
4. 下午好！
   Pinyin: xià wǔ hǎo
   Meaning: Good afternoon!
5. 晚上好
   Pinyin: wǎn shàng hǎo
   Meaning: Good evening!
6. 晚安
   Pinyin: wǎn ān
   Meaning: Good night
7. 你好吗?
   Pinyin: nǐ hǎo ma?
   Meaning: How are you?
8. 您好吗?
   Pinyin: nín hǎo ma? 
   Meaning: How are you? Used when addressing seniors or superiors to show respect.