# Fast dictionary lookups while reading text

Tags: dictionary

I am looking for a program for google drive (or for a PC, perhaps a word plugin or something like grammarly), so that I can highlight chinese text and have a bubble show up with a dictionary translation. This would be great for Chinese learning, and I'm not even sure if such a plugin for an android app with dictionary plugin exists. Thanks.

Comment: http://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/1325/3561 I use the "Zhongwen Chinese Popup Dictionary" for Google Chrome, only because it specifically mentions its entries are from CC-CEDICT where PeraPera didn't mention where the entries come from. Also, just move your Word document into Google Drive and you can use a Chrome addon with Google Docs instead :)

Answer (score 1):

Try converting the document to HTML, load it in Firefox or Chrome and use PeraPera Chinese (for [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/perapera-kun-chinese-popup-tra/), for [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/perapera-chinese-popup-di/hlcddplhfenagbaipfjhhcjmebhkkaif)). I haven't used Word for a long time, but I do remember it has an option to quick review a .doc or .docx as HTML, or similar. If not, just export it as HTML, and you can use Perapera in your browser displaying the document.