# Word list for computer UI and technical. (Simplified character, pinyin, English)

Tags: learning

My Chinese is very rusty, and I would like to learn to recognize more Chinese characters that appear in the GUI of operating systems, and popular apps.

For example:

- 取消 Qǔxiāo = Cancel
- 控制面板 Kòngzhì miànbǎn = Control Panel

I don't know if such a list would be manageable for learning and referring.

If I had to choose between learning Mainland China / Hong Kong / Taiwan versions, I would prioritize Mainland China.  Pinyin and audio pronunciation would be ideal.

Thank you all.

Comment: Baidu "计算机常见词汇 中英文 控制面板 control panel 取消 cancel" and I got [计算机英语常见词汇](http://wenku.baidu.com/link?url=Xd1vZ_MwQrSw_l-rmTuJ6b2A5cg358nAwofNGRrWyGUcT-6WccwMzmKQJKnZqm37Xc_6Tox0aSndX_kyKf2l1DipvHpiO0C6czlLnY066Zq).

Comment: Check [電腦名詞譯名](http://www.iicm.org.tw/term/) by IICM. Both mainland and Taiwan conventions are included.

Comment: @Stan Awesome link, should be edited into [Resources for learning Mandarin Chinese](http://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/1120/resources-for-learning-mandarin-chinese/1195#1195).

Comment: Stan's and songyuanyao's links are close to what I envisioned, but both do not have pinyin.  Click to listen to pronunciation would be even better.

Comment: @songyuanyao done :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have done some software translation and there are couple of ways you can go about learning UI-related language. The first thing is to start using applications (including your operating system) in Chinese. This would be the first step if you're serious about this, because otherwise it's hard to get a good grasp of the really common words

Note that words are used differently on the Mainland, Taiwan, Hong Kong and so on. Even simple words like "save" or "paste" can be different, so it's not just a matter of simplified and traditional Chinese. Sometimes it even differs between applications.

There are two good resources you can use:

1. [電腦名詞譯名](http://www.iicm.org.tw/term/termb_I.htm) - This is a huge list of computer-related words. It's extremely useful since it includes both Taiwan and Mainland usage so you can compare and choose the appropriate terms. This list is REALLY big, by the way, by far the most comprehensive resources I've found.
2. [有道](http://youdao.com/) - This is an online dictionary that also has a lot of translated articles (parallel texts). This is very good if you want to know how dialogues in programs are written, including error messages and prompts of different kinds. Searching here will take you very far, but do make sure to check examples to make sure the answer you find really is the right one.

I'm not sure if this answer is too "advanced". If you're just looking for the 100 most common computer-related words, others have provided or will provide better answers. This is the best I can offer if you want to go beyond that, though.

Answer (score 2):

Assumed that you are looking for something like that : right?

Graph      n. 图表#曲线    v.用图显示 
Border     n. 应用视窗四面的框架,边框 
Grid       n. 格子  Horizontal   n. 水平，      adj. 地平线的 
Vertical   n. 垂直     adj. 垂直的 
Range      n. 行列     v.平行，延伸 
Widget     n. 图象符号
Draw       n. 平局     v.划，绘制

if that is right, I can post or send you a word list as like.

By the way, Gcd directs you another way of localized.

Comment: Thank you. But I find that pinyin is very important for me.

Has anyone come across good Windows software where you can mouseover any chinese chars, including un-selectable UI labels, and have the pinyin and audio pronounciation appear?

Answer (score 1):

there is a simple way for you. Install some software or app which is well localized, and switch the language (from your OS setting or App configuration), and compare the words. In fact, those popular OSes are well localized, and you just need to switch the locale setting, and got UI in different languages.

BTW: zh_TW (traditional Chinese, for Hong Kong or Taiwan) and zh_CN (simplified Chinese, for China mainland) are different

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [iicm.org.tw](http://www.iicm.org.tw/term/termb_I.htm) and [youdao.com](http://youdao.com/) from [Olle's answer](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/16418/16) are good resources, but nobody has answered your question about help with pronunciation. I like to use [the Perapera plugin](http://www.perapera.org/) for Chrome or Firefox. It lets you hover over Chinese characters in your browser and it shows the meaning and pronunciation. Another option is an on-line dictionary like [mdbg.net](http://www.mdbg.net/chindict/chindict.php) that includes pronunciation.