# Would Like to learn Chinese Language

Tags: learning

I wants to know that what are the prerequisites to start Learning Chinese Language. I wants to Lear to write and to speak in Chinese.

Comment: No, you don't need any prerequisites. You just need: textbook, time, practice, ,always asking questions when you  have difficulties learning the language to your teacher or posting your questions here,  and persistence. Happy learning!

Comment: Welcome to this site. You can learn the language like how the Chinese kids learn it. The only but huge diffidence is that they have much more chances to practise and improve their language skills. However, you can definitely practise here and on the internet.

Comment: Ok can you share any source that help me to start?

Comment: Hi, you can just search for the related questions with resource as the keyword. I'm sure there are resources provided by others in previous answers.

Comment: This should be closed as it is too general and is not likely to be useful for anybody in the future, it also does not add value to the site in overall. If you need resources to learn Chinese visit this comprehensive wiki question: http://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/1120/resources-for-learning-mandarin-chinese

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the long term of view, studying PinYin is a good start. It helps you pronounce correctly every thing you learn later, which I think is the key to make people understand you :)

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, set a specific learning goal. For example, you want to learn [daily Chinese](http://www.hanbridgemandarin.com/course/chinese-language-course/oral-chinese) or [Business Chinese](http://www.hanbridgemandarin.com/course/chinese-language-course/business-chinese).

Secondly, choose the correct [learning materials](http://www.hanbridgemandarin.com/article/chinese-learning-tips/top-websites-learn-chinese-online-for-free) according to your learning goals.

Thirdly, you need to [learn some Chinese pinyin](http://www.hanbridgemandarin.com/article/chinese-learning-tips/learn-chinese-pinyin-pronunciation/) first, because pinyin is the basic of learning Chinese. Once you master Chinese pinyin, you can learn how to speak Chinese easier.

Comment: I wants to learn how to write too. And I already started with Pinyin.