# How to catch up with advanced group?

Tags: learning, resources

We live in the USA. My 12 yo daughter was transferred to a private middle school for gifted children and joined Mandarin class, where students already studied for 2 years. She is trying to catch up, but apparently it is more difficult than we thought at the beginning of the academic year. While we consider hiring a private tutor to help her to catch up, I wonder if you can suggest any resources, free and paid, which would be useful to help my daughter - websites, books, language learning packages, etc. Is there any good course on Coursera you can recommend? Is Anki convenient for learning Chinese words? Is Rosetta Stone good, in your opinion? Or is http://www.chineasy.com/ would be good for this purpose? Any ideas will be highly appreciated.

Comment: May I ask what country you are in? It sounds like an English speaking country, yet she is 12 years old. Is it a private school? Most English speaking countries allow students to take second language during junior and high school. Some schools have different Chinese levels, I- being the most beginner, II- intermediate, III-advanced so on. But for schools that have just added Chinese as a new course, there is only 1 or 2 levels. More information about school system would be helpful.

Comment: As much as I want to help, you might also have to rephrase this question to avoid it being deleted by moderators. http://chinese.stackexchange.com/tour You might have to make the question more specific.

Comment: Here is the resource page for Chinese SE that shows the different materials available. http://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/1120/resources-for-learning-mandarin-chinese

Comment: I added country (the USA) and a couple of other details. Does it sound more clear now?

Comment: This may be a better site for this question: http://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try "http://www.wannalearn.com/" search "chinese"

"http://www.openculture.com/freelanguagelessons" scroll down to "chinese" section

"https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Main_Page"