# Is there any news website that shows English translation side-by-side?

Tags: resources, websites

I'm looking for any news websites (or better, WeChat's 订阅号) that show English translation side-by-side. There is [a Japanese version of 人民网](http://j.people.com.cn/n3/2017/0929/c95961-9275505.html), but I'm looking for such news agency that show the English translation side-by-side.

Is there any such website, or if not, is there any such website that focuses on the opposite (i.e. any English-based websites that show the Mandarin side-by-side for Chinese people learning English)?

Comment: see FT中文网
双语阅读 (FT，Financial Times)  http://www.ftchinese.com/channel/ce.html

Comment: searching web with "双语阅读"  will yield more sites

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the resource curation post has [a section](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/1213/6228) on newspapers and it includes exactly the English-Chinese side-by-side websites.

Two websites are featured there, and both have WeChat 订阅号.

- 纽约时报 (NY Times) - [example](https://cn.nytimes.com/china/20171011/xi-jinping-military-china-purge/dual/)
- FT中文网 (Financial Times for Chinese) - [example](http://www.ftchinese.com/story/001074610/ce#adchannelID=1100)

It looks like the 纽约时报 side-by-side is an amazing resource. FT looks like a bit limiting in terms of articles available for side-by-side lookup.