# The New York Times - English-Chinese side-by-side bug? No 繁體 traditional characters in parallel mode?

Tags: traditional-characters

In the question "[Resources for learning Mandarin Chinese](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/1120/resources-for-learning-mandarin-chinese/1213#1213)", there is [an answer which lists some **Newspapers**](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/1213/16003), and in particular mentions:

> 纽约时报中文网 *[紐約時報中文網]* - New York Times - displays articles as English-Chinese parallel text.

At the top of the mentioned Chinese-conscious website of The New York Times (https://cn.nytimes.com/), one can switch between "**简体**" (simplified characters) and "**繁體**" (traditional characters). It works as expected when viewing the articles in Chinese-only mode.

But ... when entering the dual side-by-side English-Chinese parallel mode (once you find an article of interest, one can do so by adding `/dual/` trailing to the URL, or simply click on "**中英对照**"), all of the characters switch to "**简体**" (simplified characters).

Is there anything I am missing here, or is this really a technical issue/bug? Is there no way to show the parallel English-Chinese version of the article with "**繁體**" (traditional characters)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy way to work around: install the extension, 新同文堂 (New Tong Wen Tang), for your browser.

After clicking on "中英对照" on the web page, you then click the "繁" button in the 新同文堂 toolbar.

That's it.

You can use this extension to switch between SC and TC for any Chinese web pages.

If you open the text documents in your hard disk with the browser, you can convert them too.

I recommend all the Chinese learners installing this extension.

Answer (score 0):

## Work-around ...

If this is really overseen by The New York Times, one could convert the characters into Traditional Characters using Google Translate, or another translator.

Just paste the '`.../dual/`'-URL of interest into the text-field at Google Translate using the options: [from **Chinese** into **Traditional Chinese**](https://translate.google.com/#zh-CN/zh-TW/).

For example, after doing so:

[https://cn.nytimes.com/world/20171013/india-buddhist-muslim-marriage`/dual/`](https://cn.nytimes.com/world/20171013/india-buddhist-muslim-marriage/dual/)

will become

[`https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=zh-CN&tl=zh-TW&u=`ttps://cn.nytimes.com/world/20171013/india-buddhist-muslim-marriage`/dual/`](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=zh-CN&tl=zh-TW&u=ttps://cn.nytimes.com/world/20171013/india-buddhist-muslim-marriage/dual/)

## ... or boycott until fixed

If this is too much a hassle, until The New York Times fixes this glitch, one can switch to another newspaper such as FT中文網 (FT中文网) - The Financial Times. To read an article in side-by-side English-Chinese parallel mode, just add `/ce` to the main part of the URL. As in e.g. [http://big5.ftchinese.com/story/001074653/`ce`](http://big5.ftchinese.com/story/001074653/ce) The site allows you to choose between Traditional and Simplified Chinese characters (currently at the utmost top-left) without a glitch: simply change "**简体中文**" (meaning simplified Chinese characters) into "**繁體中文**" (meaning traditional Chinese characters) or vice versa.