# Is there a list of medicinal plants and their translations in Mandarin?

Tags: resources

I am interested in both learning Mandarin and the names of traditional medicinal plants in China. I am also interested in the history of herbal medicine in China, and a resource to study this in English would help me to learn some more basic Mandarin vocabulary or ideas for basic phrases like the names of teas or preparations and tools used in Chinese medicine.

Comment: Should be closed as duplicate of the [resources thread](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/1120). The rresource referenced in the answer has now been included in the appropriate list in that thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try the [Chinese Medicinal Material Images Database](https://library.hkbu.edu.hk/electronic/libdbs/mmd/), which is maintained by the Hong Kong Baptist University.

It contains 420+ entries, each with name in traditional Chinese, English and Latin; description and usage.

Answer (score -1):

My mother often prescribed herbs sold under the ***seven forests*** brand name.

I have never read the book myself, but it seems like, Seven Forests has published a book titled, [A Bag of Pearls](https://www.google.com/search?q=bag%20of%20pearls.book&oq=bag%20of%20pearls.book&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i22i30j0i390i650l5.5624j0j7&client=ms-android-verizon&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8#ip=1) containing a handful of the names of Chinese herbs.

href = "https://www.goldenneedleonline.com/A-Bag-of-Pearls.html">
  
src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CWKg.gif"