# Which book or website is recommended for learning Chinese grammar in 2022?

Tags: books, reference-materials

Yesterday I've started learning Chinese, and I've been using Duolingo only for now.

The most thing which I am irritating about Duolingo is that phonetic alphabets (Pinyin) are omited frequently in problems like quizzes.

I am not a genius so I cannot memorize a pronunciation of a term in one time.

So I am thinking changing the app or learning material(s).

For me, I want to be recommended some good grammar book or grammar website of Chinese.

BTW should I avoid using free materials of natural language learning rather than using stuff which was made with incentives?

Comment: The [Chinese Grammar Wiki](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Main_Page).  This question probably should be closed as a duplicate of [Resources for learning Mandarin Chinese](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/1120/resources-for-learning-mandarin-chinese), but that list is a bit short on grammar textbooks.

Comment: I'll refer the both sites. BTW my this name "CRT" is derived from Chinese Remainder Theorem which I can prove :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Pinyin rules

Integrated Chinese 4th Edition, Volume 1 Textbook:This book has a good grasp of pinyin rules. You will learn about the pronunciation of each character and the difference in the tones used.

- Chinese Reader

Pleco汉语词典(app):The user interface of this application is currently only in English, with an integrated dictionary/document reader/word card system. The explanation next to each Chinese character will be annotated with pinyin.

- Sentence structure

Beijing University Edition Chinese as a Foreign Language Textbook - Grammar Course Series

- As for whether to choose paid materials, I personally think it is not necessary for the time being. I prefer to pay for the direction of learning, rather than the content of the course itself, because the basic content is similar. Of course, if you want to lay a solid foundation, it is also good to have effective interaction, it depends on your thinking.